# Displaying an image from a QAbstractTableModel

Tags: qt, qt4

I am trying to display an image from a `QAbstractTableModel`. I tried returning a `QPixmap` as the `QVariant` of `data()`, but it only produces empty cells, when I would expect every cell in the second column to have a 20x20 black square.

This is my code currently:

```
QVariant MySqlTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &idx, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole && idx.column() == 1) {
        QPixmap pixmap(20,20);
        QColor black(0,0,0);
        pixmap.fill(black);
        return pixmap;
    }

    return QSqlTableModel::data(idx, role);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only `QVariant`s that can be converted to string can be returned for the role `Qt::DisplayRole` with the standard delegate.

You can show the image by returning it for the role `Qt::DecorationRole`

```
QVariant MySqlTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &idx, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const
{
    if (idx.column() == 1) {
        if (role == Qt::DecorationRole) {
            QPixmap pixmap(20,20);
            QColor black(0,0,0);
            pixmap.fill(black);
            return pixmap;
        } else if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
            // For Qt::DisplayRole return an empty string, otherwise
            // you will have *both* text and image displayed.
            return "";
        }
    }

    return QSqlTableModel::data(idx, role);
}
```

Or write your own delegate to do the painting yourself. See [QStyledItemDelegate documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstyleditemdelegate.html#details) for more details.

Comment: Yea I figured it could be done with a delegate, but that seemed like overkill. I guess there is no easier way? Also, if I only want to apply the delegate to a specific column, is there a way to do that? Currently I have set the delegate to the whole TableView using setItemDelegate. Then I have to do the column check (to see which column the images are displayed in) in the data() function of the model as well as the paint() function of the delegate - this seems like code duplication... is there a better way?

Comment: The easier way is to use `Qt::DecorationRole` without using a delegate. But you can set a delegate for a column with `setItemDelegateForColumn`.

Comment: Ah, how could I miss setItemDelegateForColumn ? Thanks!